# What are the frame_id and frame fields in ser.send() from python-xbee?

Tags: python, xbee

[python-xbee](http://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/) makes it easier to deal with XBee in API mode.  But documentation is very short.
Could anyone tell me what's `frame` and `frame_id`?  I can use:

```
ser.send('at', frame_id='A', command='IS')
```

to send an IS command.  Also OK with `frame_id='A'` replaced with `frame='A'` or `'B'` or `'C'`.  So I just wonder what is the `frame` and `frame_id` stand for in the library.

Comment: Judging by the 2.0.0 documentation, `frame_id` might just be the old name for the `frame` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the sparse documentation. I haven't gotten around to improving it yet.

frame_id is an optional parameter that helps one match up responses to their associated requests. When a frame id is provided, the response message for that request will have a matching frame id.

For example, if I wanted to design a high-throughput system, I might want it to react to events asynchronously. In this manner, I might want to issue a series of requests to an XBee device before the XBee could possibly respond to any of them.

By assigning a temporarily unique frame id to each request before it is sent, a system could then wait and react to each response message by matching up the frame id field to the initial request's assigned frame id.

If no frame id is provided, then the response from the XBee will also lack a frame id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But there is also a 'frame' parameter,It can also set to 'A' or 'B' or something else.So what is frame parameter mean?

Comment: I can't speak for `python-xbee`, but a `frame_id` of `0` (not `'0'`, but actual `0`) on many frame types means "don't send a response".  A value of 1 to 255 can be used to match the response to a specific request.